# Does Apple support using Xcode 9 to build and run on an iOS 10 device?

Tags: ios, xcode

Does Apple support using Xcode 9 to build and run on an iOS 10 device?

I feel like this should be obvious but it’s not to me.

In particular, I want to do more than just set the deployment target to 10. I want to be able to plugin an iOS 10 device and actually run code compiled on Xcode 9.

It’s also valuable that Apple more or less support this, or it will be less reliable I presume.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: works, been using Xcode 9 GM with my iOS 10 devices with no issues

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this was a silly question. The answer is yes. Or maybe, yes obviously.